# Read xls sheet and write it into database using EXcel reader and writer classes

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import

I have used Two files to read and write .xls files in to a MySql database which I downloaded from the link below:

https://major.io/2008/11/07/importing-excel-files-into-mysql-with-php/

I have written all the code that is necessary in this method but there is an error:

> The filename C:\Users\rasha\Desktop\test.xls is not readable

The code that I have written in Php is:

```
require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read('C:\Users\rasha\Desktop\test.xls');
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","localhost:3306");
mysql_select_db("test",$conn);
```

Comment: There seems to be a permission problem with your XLS file. Also, please don't use `mysql_*` functions, as they are deprecated and removed from PHP7.

Comment: there is no issue with permission , could you help in this?